# Why is AVCaptureSession method canAddOutput returning false?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, avcapturesession

I'm trying to build a camera app, and I'm trying to set up my capture session within viewDidLoad() in my main view controller. For some reason, whenever I run the app on my phone, AVCaptureSession method canAddOutput is evaluated as false:

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput!
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

//MARK: Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    //Ask permission to camera
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back)
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) in
        if granted {
            print("granted")
            //Set up session
            if let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
                print("Input = device")
                if (self.captureSession.canAddInput(input)) {
                    self.captureSession.addInput(input)
                    print("Input added to capture session")
                    if (self.captureSession.canAddOutput(self.photoOutput)) {
                        print("Output added to capture session")
                        self.captureSession.addOutput(self.photoOutput)
                        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
                        self.previewLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds
                        self.previewView.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer!)
                        self.captureSession.startRunning()
                        print("Session is running")
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            print("Goodbye")
        }
    })

}
```

Unfortunately, I can only get it to print up until "Input added to capture session". Any suggestions would help - thanks!

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to `self.photoOutput`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove previous outputs added in session. you can use for loop  for that.

`for outputs in captureSession.outputs{ captureSession.removeOutput(outputs) }`

then try to add new out put